# Keyboard and trackpad unrepsonsive after opening lid to wake on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, suspend, touchpad

After upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, the keyboard and trackpad on my Dell laptop become unresponsive after the computer has been closed and reopened.  That is, after sleep then wake.

The touch-screen however does still work, and so I can bring up an on-screen keyboard and log in that way.  But even after logging in, the keyboard and trackpad are still unresponsive.  Only a reboot fixes the issue.

This is incredibly annoying.  The only way around this is to completely shut down the laptop each time I use it before closing the lid.  But that of course is less than ideal.

I did notice some other similar issues out there, but they were somewhat older, so I'm not sure it's the same issue.  For example, I found a github issue that described this for Pop OS, which is based on Ubuntu: https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/399
But that issue is to date unresolved.

This happens about 50% of the time.  So it's not every time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whats in your kernel logs, system logs?